# How to insert column in Group Header SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

When I add parent group in SSRS report, and and when I tried to insert a column just like deptno to show the result as a deptno, it always insert deptno as Sum(deptno), while I need only deptno, how can i solve this i[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLNGI.png)ssue, any body can help me please

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you place the expression and what datatype the field is, SSRS will use the most suitable expression. In your case I assume that `DEPTNO` is numeric so SSRS just assumes you wanted to sum the value up, it has no idea of what the data means.

You can easily fix this.

Depending on the scope of the expression, in other words where the expression is placed in terms of row or column groups you can right-click the text box, choose `Expression` then change the expression to either.

1. `=Fields!DEPTNO.Value`
2. `=FIRST(Fields!DEPTNO.Value)`